# Inherent components of Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I try to learn one CMS for a new website, and I have some questions about Joomla.

What of the items below are not included as an inherent component of Joomla ?

1) Templates

2) Components

3) Social Media

4) User Management

Answer (score 1):

Answer : Social Media

Information :

Templates : you must download them from a store.True..but you can install joomla templates into the system, so it already supports it (even if it doesn't have them)

Components : is kind of the term they use to describe plugins
and technically "components" are not built-in, but if you ask if joomla supports components, the answer is yes

Social Media : does joomla let you share photos and like them and share with others? Joomla isn't a 2nd facebook

User Management : it has a user backend, so yes, it has a built-in user management system